# How to use .fileinput() with webforms c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, webforms

I have the following code in ASP.Net C#:

```
private void InicializaControleUpload()
{
    string  urlUpload = "UploadTelaHandler.ashx?numDetalhe=";
    int tamanhoUpload = Convert.ToInt32(this.appSettingsBLL.GetAppSetting("TAMANHO_UPLOAD").KeyValue);
    string js = "$('#file1').fileinput({";
        js += "uploadUrl: \"" + urlUpload + "\",";
        js += "uploadAsync: true,";
        js += "maxFileCount: 3,";
        js += "validateInitialCount: true,";
        js += "overwriteInitial: false,";
        js += "maxFileSize: " + (tamanhoUpload / 1024) + ",";
        js += "'allowedPreviewTypes': 'image',";
        js += "'previewFileType': 'image',";
        js += "'allowedFileExtensions': ['jpg','gif','png','bmp']";
        js += "});";
    js += System.Environment.NewLine;
    JavascriptBox.WriteJavascriptJquery(this.Page, this.GetType(), fileUploadClient", js);
}

public static void WriteJavascriptJquery(Page page, Type type, string key, string script)
{
    string scriptComJquery = "$(function() {" + script + "});";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, type, key, scriptComJquery, true);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Anexar captura de tela caso necessário</label>
    <input id="file1" type="file" multiple class="btn btn-default btn-xs" />                     
</div>
```

This is the way it is my implementation to loading images, but at the moment of upload file show this error:

> "NameofFile".jpg: [object Object]

Can someone help me?

Comment: there are some slight syntax issues:
method "InicializaControlUpload()", last line: there is an extra double quote after fileUploadClient;

composition of the js string: some key names are in single quotes, some are not. IMO all should be without;

if none of this helps, please give more context: at which stage of execution is this "[object Object]" message generated/shown?

Comment: I tried already take the single quotes of all , but don't resolved.

Yes, "[object Object]" is message generated